# Where do I set the CName record? On the Registrar or on Amazon?

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, hosting

I have a domain registered with Fasthosts and I have pointed all the nameservers for the domain...mydomain.com at the Amazon nameservers.

I have an Amazon EC2 cloud instance with an Elastic IP and Route 53 set up.

I wan't to set up an extra domain. So blog.mydomain.com. I just don't know if I should set up a CName record? And if so where do I do it? At fasthosts or at amazon level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this Amazon article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html) to create a subdomain using Route 53.